# How I can customize google font in email template

Tags: google-font-api

I have an email html  and I would like to use font Poppins to display text in my email.
However, It's not working. 
I searched and found some solutions, but it's still not working.

https://css-tricks.com/kinda-can-use-custom-fonts-html-emails/

https://mailbakery.com/blog/fonts-html-emails-limitations-solutions-industry-standards/

https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read the help section on "How to ask". You should show some effort in solving your problem and post the code you are trying to write.

Comment: I tried but it's not working. This is my code : https://codepen.io/ngatdo2501/pen/KRbPQR

Answer (score 1):

### **Add a Google Font to Your Template**

1. Search for your Google font here: https://fonts.google.com.
2. Next, click on the font and click the Select This Font button on the
   upper right.
3. After selecting the font, click on the Family Selected window that is 
   minimized at the bottom of your browser.
4. Make sure you're in the Embed tab, then navigate to @Import
   Visit here: https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/article_attachments/115000293152/2017-05-02_14-33-08.png for example image.
5. Here, you will see the import URL for the font. Copy this URL. In
   this example, the URL is:
   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto.
6. In your Klaviyo template, find and edit the first text block in your
   email. Click on the Source button to view the raw HTML.

Then, add the following HTML. This includes the font's import URL and specifies which HTML elements will use that font:

```css
<style type="text/css">  
   @import url('INSERT_FONT_URL'); 
   p, h1, h2, h3 {  
       font-family: 'INSERT_FONT_NAME', 'INSERT_A_FALLBACK_FONT';  
       } 
</style>
```

When you save the block, you'll see the new fonts being used.

Comment: Thanks for your helps.